# C sockets: why is my server appending extra characters in the end?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server

I am writing a simple server/client socket in C. The client asks the user to input a message and the server responds by repeating the same. The problem is when I send a message from the client the server responds back by appending extra character. How do I fix this.

This is my Client code

```
while(1) {
    bzero(buffer, BUFSIZE);
    printf("Enter Message: ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    //send some data
    if(send(socket_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) <0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"sending failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
//receive a reply from the server
if(recv(socket_fd, server_reply, BUFSIZE,0)<0)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"failed to reply. \n");
    break;
}
fprintf(stdout, "Reply: %s\n ", servreply);

}
```

This is my server code

```
 int read_size;
    while((read_size = recv(client_socket_fd, buffer, BUFSIZE,0))>0)
    {

        // Reply back to the client
        if (0 > write(client_socket_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "could not write back to socket\n");
        } else {
            fprintf(stdout, "message back to client\n");
        }
    }
    if(read_size==0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"disconnected.\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size==-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "error.\n");
    }
```

This is the output

```
 Enter Message: welcome
Reply: welcome
 Enter Message: hello
Reply: hellome
 Enter Message: hi
Reply: hillome
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a *string* in order to use `strlen()`. Your arrays are not strings, rely on `read_size` instead for the length of the buffer.

Strings in [c](/questions/tagged/c) are just a sequence of printable characters followed by a `'\0'`, and none of your arrays has any `'\0'` so `strlen()` is causing undefined behavior. The `strlen()` function actually scans the *string* until it finds the `'\0'` and in the process it counts how many characters were there.

Comment: Thank you. In addition can you please explain when enter a message like "How are you", the server responds in different lines."How" "are" and "you" are on three different lines

Comment: Because that's how it works. You need to 1. Use `select` and read until there is nothing more to read, but this is tricky. 2. Use a messaging protocol to assemble a message and reconstruct it when it reaches the other party.

Answer (score 0):

@Iharob's answer is correct. Basically, change the line:

```
write(client_socket_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer))
```

to:

```
write(client_socket_fd, buffer, read_size)
```

Answer (score -1):

It isn't. You are printing junk at the end of your buffer. You're also ignoring end of stream.

```
if(recv(socket_fd, server_reply, BUFSIZE,0)<0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"failed to reply. \n");
    break;
}
fprintf(stdout, "Reply: %s\n ", servreply);
```

should be

```
int count;
if((count = recv(socket_fd, server_reply, BUFSIZE,0))<0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"failed to reply. \n");
    break;
}
else if (count == 0) {
    // EOS
    fprintf(stderr, "peer has disconnected.\n");
    break;
} else {  
    fprintf(stdout, "Reply: %.*s\n ", count, servreply);
}
```

Your 'write back to the client' is also incorrect:

```
if (0 > write(client_socket_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer))) {
```

should be

```
if (0 > write(client_socket_fd, buffer, read_size)) {
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this and this helped. However, when I enter a string like "How are you", it displays it on different lines.

Comment: Possibly `scanf()` is tokenizing at the spaces. It has nothing to do with the question you asked.