# Result of sizeof differs from size of character string

Tags: c, linux, string, pointers

Why is the sizeof "Hello World!!" only showing up as 8?
I am trying to send this through send() in a TCP client/ server program and can not send the whole character array because sizeof doesnt seem to be reading correctly

```
char *message = "Hello World!!";
int test = sizeof message;
int test2 = sizeof 'H';
printf("%d", test);
printf("%d", test2);
```

**Results:**

(gdb) print test

$1 = 8

(gdb) print test2

$2 = 4

This is the code snippent from my program that is only sending "Hello Wo"

```
if((numbytes = send(sockfd, message, sizeof message, 0)) == -1){
    perror("recv");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof some_pointer` returns the size of the ***pointer***, not what it might point to. If you want to get the length of a null-terminated string use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen). And do note that `strlen` *doesn't* include the terminator.

Comment: `sizeof pointer != sizeof array` ... `sizeof message != sizeof "Hello World!!"` arrays are not pointers; pointers are not arrays. I suggest you read section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
char *message = "Hello World!!";
int test = sizeof message;
```

returns the size of the *pointer*, which in your system is of size 8.

Read more in [Size of pointer of integer type vs Size of int*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436432/size-of-pointer-of-integer-type-vs-size-of-int).

As @SomeProgrammerDude said, use [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) to get the length of a C string (i.e. a null-terminated string).

Comment: Ok, i didnt know the type of the pointer doesnt matter, thats why I was thrown off taking the size of 'H' and only getting 4. But I cant use strlen() with out adding the null terminator to the char array because it can cause undefined behavior, correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950202/c-sockets-why-is-my-server-appending-extra-characters-in-the-end

Comment: The array `"hi"` has three elements, the last of which is `'\0'`

Comment: The size of 'H' is due to integer promotion. 'H' is a char, but is promoted to integer by any operation (including sizeof()).

Comment: @AlainMerigot: `'H'` is an `int` in C (I believe C++ has different rules).

Comment: It is not NULL only nul or zero terminated. NULL has a special meaning in C

Comment: null it is then @P__J__, thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: The C standard does not require all pointers to be the same size; pointers of different types may have different sizes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I had forgotten [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-sizes), although I had upvoted, answer updated, thank you very match, good catch!